# questions about randint and if

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, random

```py
def rng():
    return randint(1, 100)
```

is

```py
if rng() <= x and rng() <= y and rng() <= z:
   .....
```

The same as
is

```py
if rng() <= x and y and z:
   .....
```

What im trying to do is take a number from the function `rng()` then use it to compare with the variables inside the `if` statement

and i'm questioning whether on the first version, the `rng()` is ran 3 times making it 3 different numbers for each compare and not the same number.

or the second version can work

Comment: *Neither* of those code snippets will work; one picks three different random numbers, the other only compares to x. Assign the return value to a variable, there's no need to try and inline everything.

Comment: how can do it then ?

Comment: Just assign e.g. `value = rng()`, then use `value` in the comparisons.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 1):

As @jonsharpe indicated, neither of those would work. The second one would be nonsensical (that isn't how `and` works) while the first would make more sense but still fail. It would fail because it will compute three different random numbers and not a single one. You would need to do something like:

```
r = rng()
if r <= x and r <= y and r <= z:
    #do something
```

In this special case, you could also use the `min` operator:

```
if rng() <= min(x,y,z):
    #do something
```

although obviously not all comparisons involving `r` can be reduced to just 1.

Comment: You should probably also use `r = rng()` in the second case, using `min`

Comment: @tobias_k it depends on what OP is doing this for. If the point is to have the code in the body of the `if` execute with a specific probability which depends on `x,y,z,` and there is no further role for `r` to play, then defining `r` at all would be superfluous.